# Failed to lazily initialize a collection while using setter method for collection

Tags: hibernate, lazy-initialization

I am running below method to add random users to groups. As UserGroup is child and User is parent in bidirectional relationship I am not using this.users = users in setter as I need first to remove current group from all users that are not in the list and then add current group to users from the list that are not already in this group. However passing **userlisToAdd** set of users give me error. Initializint collection by calling this.users = users will break my code logic as I need to get old collection first to iterate through, but can't do that as well as collection is not initiallized. What is other option to initialize collection from inside the entity in setUsers method?

> Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily
>   initialize a collection of role:
>   it.akademija.wizards.entities.UserGroup.users, could not initialize
>   proxy - no Session
>           at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:597)
>           at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:216)
>           at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:160)
>           at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:168)
>           at java.util.HashSet.(HashSet.java:119)
>           at it.akademija.wizards.entities.UserGroup.setUsers(UserGroup.java:83)
>           at it.akademija.wizards.DataBaseFillerWithFaker.addUsersToGroups(DataBaseFillerWithFaker.java:140)
>           at it.akademija.wizards.DataBaseFillerWithFaker.fillInDatabaseWithData(DataBaseFillerWithFaker.java:52)
>           at it.akademija.wizards.DataBaseFillerWithFaker$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f09a7960.invoke()
>           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684)
>           at it.akademija.wizards.DataBaseFillerWithFaker$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5d876d6.fillInDatabaseWithData()
>           at it.akademija.wizards.CommandLineAppRunner.run(CommandLineAppRunner.java:79)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813)
>           ... 10 common frames omitted

**Method to add users list to group**

```
   @Transactional
   public void addUsersToGroups() {
    List<User> users = userRepository.findAll().stream().filter(user -> !user.isAdmin()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<UserGroup> groups = userGroupRepository.findAll();

    for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {
        int usersToAdd = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * users.size() + 1);
        UserGroup userGroup = groups.get(i);

        // Add users to group
        Set<User> usersListToAdd = new HashSet<>();
        for (int y = 0; y < usersToAdd; y++) {
            User user = users.get((int) Math.floor(Math.random() * usersToAdd));
            usersListToAdd.add(user);
        }
        userGroup.setUsers(usersListToAdd);
        // Save group to database
        userGroupRepository.save(userGroup);
    }
}
```

**UserGroup entity**

```
@Entity
public class UserGroup {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userGroups")
    private Set<User> users;

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        Set<User> oldUserList = new HashSet<>(this.users);
        oldUserList.stream().filter(user -> !users.contains(user)).forEach(user -> user.removeGroup(this));
        users.stream().filter(user -> !oldUserList.contains(user)).forEach(user -> user.addGroup(this));
    }

}
```

**ComandLineRunner**

```
@Component
public class CommandLineAppRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

// Autowirder classes here

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        // Change if you want to fill in databse with random data on startup
        boolean fillInDatabase = true;
        int groups = 12;
        int users = 10000;
        int docTypes = 20;
        int avqDocsForUser = 20;

        // ONLY FOR FIRST RUN WITH EMPTY DATABASE AND FILL IN ENABLED
        if (fillInDatabase
                && roleRepository.count() == 0
                && userRepository.count() == 0
                && userGroupRepository.count() == 0
                && documentRepository.count() == 0
                && documentTypeRepository.count() == 0) {


            dataBaseFillerWithFaker.fillInDatabaseWithData(groups, users, docTypes, avqDocsForUser);
        }

/// Some other unrelated code
```

**Database Filler**

```
@Service
public class DataBaseFillerWithFaker {

// Autowired injections

    public void fillInDatabaseWithData(int groups, int users, int docTypes, int avgDocsForUser) {
        addUsersToGroups();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addUsersToGroups() {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll().stream().filter(user -> !user.isAdmin()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<UserGroup> groups = userGroupRepository.findAll();

        for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {
            int usersToAdd = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * users.size() + 1);
            UserGroup userGroup = groups.get(i);

            // Add users to group
            Set<User> usersListToAdd = new HashSet<>();
            for (int y = 0; y < usersToAdd; y++) {
                User user = users.get((int) Math.floor(Math.random() * usersToAdd));
                usersListToAdd.add(user);
            }
            userGroup.setUsers(usersListToAdd);
            // Save group to database
            userGroupRepository.save(userGroup);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you invoking the `addUsersToGroups` method?

Comment: It is coming from rest controller

Comment: And where is the `addUsersToGroups` method?

Comment: It is the first code attached. I added rest controller method as well, but I guess it has nothing to do with the issue

Comment: That's a lie, as in controller there is `addUsersToGroup` with 2 parameters and in first snippet, there's parameterless `addUsersToGroups`

Comment: Dear, Andronicus, you are totally right. My bad. I refered to wrong method. This addUsersToGroup method is called by DatabaseFiller class which called by ComandLineRunner on start up of Spring Boot app. Edited my code